# Using dynamic icons for android push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification

Is it possible for me to pass the url of the images down to the android device so that the push notification in the system tray will be able to have dynamic icon images?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum packet size of a GCM message 4KB. You could in theory pass the bitmap within this packet and load it as long as you do not exceed the packet limit.

How many icons are we talking about here? You could ship them with your app and push down the name of the icon to use when displaying the notification.